# For loop not working as expected (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I understand the basic premise of a for loop with JavaScript, however the use of the `.each` evades me.

```
var col = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    $('p').html(col[i]);
}
```

Which churns out:

```
<p> 6 </p>
<p> 6 </p>
<p> 6 </p>
```

When I was expecting:

```
<p> 1 </p>
<p> 2 </p>
<p> 3 </p>
```

Why is this not working as expected, and how could it be done with jQuery, rather than pure JavaScript?

http://jsfiddle.net/rgD92/2/

Comment: you have a kind of nested loop affecting last value to all P elements: `$('p')` target all P elements, so at each loop iteration, you are updating value for all these elements

Comment: Aah okay. How do you mean nested loop — loop within a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the code below](http://jsfiddle.net/kCQv8/):

```
var col = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
$('p').each(function(index){
    $(this).text(col[index]);
});
```

Why your code doesn't work?

When you iterate the "col" list inside the loop, you took all references `<p>` elements, when the last interaction occurred, the number 6 will be set in all `<p>` elements.

**Update:**

If you have more `<p>` elements than numbers in `col` list, you can use `%` operator like the code below:

```
var col = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$('p').each(function(index){
    $(this).text(col[index % col.length]);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XzqBE/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's great — you've really helped. Also, how would I get the loop to start again once the col array has ran out? It loops through all the numbers, not through all the `p` tags. Would it involve the modulo % operator?

Comment: @tmyie I updated the answer. Basically I altered the index to use the % operator. I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's perfect — I don't quite understand the logic of that, however.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select which `p` to be updated also, in every iteration you are updating all the `p` elements in the document.

In the given sample you can use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select the `p` element sequentially.

```
for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    $('p').eq(i).html(col[i]);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cHft8/)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do:

```
$('p').text(function(i){
    return col[i];
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HsskL/).

This will allow jQuery to iterate over the collection itself, rather than using an explicit for loop.

If, as your comment to another answer suggests, you want the `col` text/contents to loop, should the array be shorter than the number of `p` elements:

```
$('p').text(function(i){
    return col[i % col.length];
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HsskL/1/).

References:

- [JavaScript Arithmetic Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 1):

Using `jQuery` and `each()`, you could do:

```
var col = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
$("p").each(function(i) {
    $(this).html(col[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$('p')` selector selects all `p`'s on page and your loop updates all `p`'s too.

```
var col = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    $('p:eq(' + i + ')').html(col[i]);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgD92/3/)